# Creating a new directory from the application

Tags: tomcat, directory, webdav

Using tomcat webdav, currently I am able to upload files/documents into a particular webdav location. To this extent, it is fine.

However now I have a requirement that I have to create a new directory (based on a condition) in the webdav location and upload the files or documents into that newly created directory.

This I have to achieve through Java.
I tried to create a directory using file.mkdir(). But it is returning false to me.

Can anyone throw some light how can I overcome this situation?

Kind regards

Subbu

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to the target directory? Is the WebDAV server the place where the code lives to create this directory?

Comment: Yes, I have the permissions.
And NO, that it is a separate application and would like to create folder/directory in the webdav directory.

Comment: Is there any reason not to call the WebDAV server using HTTP and issue a `MKCOL` request?

Comment: How to do it? Can you please explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an HTTP connection to your WebDAV service and issue a MKCOL request (MKCOL is just like GET, POST, etc.). Something like this:

```
MKCOL /the/directory/you/want/to/create HTTP/1.1
```

You should expect a 201 response. If you get something else, it means that the directory creation has failed.

Comment: Thank you very much, Christopher.
Now I am able to create a folder in webdav.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Christopher!!

I would like to illustrate my code to create a webdav folder using a sample application.

```
public class CreateWebdavFolderUsingHttpClient {

    private static String url = "http://localhost:8081/webdav/subbu/MyWebdavFolder";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String response = null;
        /* Create an instance of HttpClient.*/
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.getState().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("tomcat", "tomcat"));

        DavMethod method = new MkColMethod(url);
        try {
            client.executeMethod(method);
            response = method.getStatusCode() + " - " + method.getStatusText();
            client.executeMethod(new MkColMethod(url + "/10300"));
            response = method.getStatusCode() + " - " + method.getStatusText();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Catch error
        } finally {
            method.releaseConnection();
        }
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to check the return code of the first `executeMethod` call -- otherwise the second one will likely fail. Also, if `releaseConnection` must be called on the `Method` object, make sure that you call it on the object created on the line containing `"/10300"`.